# GraphQL returns null address if optional telephone is set as empty string

Tags: magento2.4.2

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Using GraphQL mutation, add a product to Cart
2. Set Shipping Addresses on cart using the following Mutation

```
mutation {
  setShippingAddressesOnCart(
    input: {
      cart_id: "zcatHMtPLY8M8hs0I1ALNihsk8bdRlUI"
      shipping_addresses: [
        {
          address: {
            firstname: "Bob"
            lastname: "Roll"
            company: "Magento"
            street: ["Magento Pkwy", "Main Street"]
            city: "Austin"
            region: "AN"
            region_id: 533
            postcode: "78758"
            country_code: "IN"
            telephone: "" #<---- note that the telephone is an empty string. 
            save_in_address_book: false
          },
       }
      ]
    }
  ) {
    cart {
      shipping_addresses {
        firstname
        lastname
        company
        street
        city
        region {
          code
          label
        }
        postcode
        telephone
        country {
          code
          label
        }
        pickup_location_code
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "setShippingAddressesOnCart": {
      "cart": {
        "shipping_addresses": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried few things but they didn't work, Does any knows how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding following schema.graphqls

```
interface CartAddressInterface @typeResolver(class: "\\Magento\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\CartAddressTypeResolver") {
    firstname: String!
    lastname: String!
    company: String
    street: [String!]!
    city: String!
    region: CartAddressRegion
    postcode: String
    country: CartAddressCountry!
    telephone: String
}

input CartAddressInput {
    firstname: String!
    lastname: String!
    company: String
    street: [String!]!
    city: String!
    region: String
    region_id: Int
    postcode: String
    country_code: String!
    telephone: String
    save_in_address_book: Boolean @doc(description: "Determines whether to save the address in the customer's address book. The default value is true")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone have idea how to get values of new custom columns created in DB in table quote_address?

I have added 2 new columns in quote_address table.
I am passing some value to those and it is getting saved in table also.
But the GQL is retuning them blank.
Here is my GQL.

```
mutation {
  setShippingAddressesOnCart(
    input: {
      cart_id: "C9n2s6H9Gx3JRjcFxInSuJN1HUTXpsbQ"
      shipping_addresses: [
        {
          address: {
            firstname: "test"
            lastname: "test"
            region: "test"
            city: "test"
            country_code: "SA"
            street:["as"]
            area:"my area shipping"
            apartment:"my apartment shipping"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ) {
    cart {
      items {
        id
      }
      shipping_addresses {
            id 
            customer_address_id
            area
            apartment
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And he is what i get in response

```
{
    "data": {
        "setShippingAddressesOnCart": {
            "cart": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": "8296146"
                    }
                ],
                "shipping_addresses": [
                    {
                        "id": 7624024,
                        "customer_address_id": null,
                        "area": null,
                        "apartment": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "area" and "apartment" should not come null. As the values are getting saved in DB.